# Linq lambda for searching a List within a List, finding a match, then deleting it from the list

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I'm trying to learn Linq and I need help with a method that searches a List within a List, finds a match, and deletes it. For example, imagine I have a class called `Student`:

```
public class Student
{
   string FirstName;
   string LastName;
}
```

Then imagine I have another class called `Classroom`, which has a `List<Student>`:

```
public class Classroom
{
   List<Student> Students;
}
```

And finally, I have one more class, called `School`, which has a list of `Classrooms`:

```
public class School
{
   List<Classroom> Classrooms;
}
```

Then, I need a method that takes in a `Student` object, checks to see if the student is in the school, and deletes them if they are. If they're in the school, the method should delete them and return true. If they're not in the school, the method should return false and take no action. Here's an example using foreach loops, which I want to get rid of:

```
public bool RemoveStudentFromSchool(Student student)
{
   foreach (Classroom c in Classrooms)
   {
      foreach (Student s in c.Students)
      {
         if ((student.FirstName == s.FirstName) && (student.LastName == s.LastName))
         {
            s.Remove(student);

            return true;
         }
      }
   }

   return false;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This assumes a student can only be in one room and `Student` is `IEquatable` on first and last name (or the references are equal):

```
var roomWithStudent = Classrooms.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Students.Any(s => s.Equals(student));
if (roomWithStudent != null)
{
    roomWithStudent.Remove(student);
    return true;
}
return false;
```

An alternative approach if `Student` is not `IEquatable` and the search object passed in is not necessarily the same reference:

```
var roomWithStudent = Classrooms
                        .SelectMany(c => c.Students.Select(s => new { Room = c, Student = s }))
                        .Where(rs => (student.FirstName == rs.Student.FirstName) && (student.LastName == rs.Student.LastName))
                        .FirstOrDefault();

if (roomWithStudent != null)
{
    roomWithStudent.Room.Students.Remove(roomWithStudent.Student);
    return true;
}
return false;
```

Comment: should rather be: Any(s => (student.FirstName == s.FirstName && student.LastName == s.LastName))

Comment: @ub1k: Not sure what exactly you mean - can you elaborate?

Comment: @ub1k chris mentions that the first approach is with IEquatable which would mean he should have done his own implementation of equals and gethashcode anyway

Comment: from my experience the whole logical statement in lambda expression must be in one parenthesis. Check it yourself. it's a compiler issue I believe.

Comment: @ub1k: I don't think so. Works fine for me like this in VS2010

Answer (score 1):

What about an extension method..

```
public static bool RemoveFromRoom(this Student student,School school)
{
    if (student == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("student");
    if (school == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("school");
    bool ret = false;
    var room = school.Classrooms.SingleOrDefault(cr=>cr.Students.Contains(student));
    if (room !=null)
    {
        ret = true;
        room.Students.Remove(student);
    }

    return ret;
}
```

Usage

```
student.RemoveFromRoom(instanceOfSchool);
```

Or...

```
public static bool RemoveStudentFromRoom(this School school,Student student)
{
    if (student == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("student");
    if (school == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("school");
    bool ret = false;
    var room = school.Classrooms.SingleOrDefault(cr=>cr.Students.Contains(student));
    if (room !=null)
    {
        ret = true;
        room.Students.Remove(student);
    }

    return ret;
}
```

Usage

```
instanceOfSchool.RemoveStudentFromRoom(student);
```

Comment: +1, I will make it an extension method as well. Thanks for your contribution.